# How to automatically authenticate and query Flickr

Tags: oauth, flickr

I want to get a listing of my photos from Flickr's API but all of the APIs out there seem to have the same basic behavior: they forward you to a login prompt. My application needs to automatically authenticate using Flickr OAuth so that the user doesn't have to know the login credentials.

Comment: Apparently, I'm the only one who has viewed this post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to authenticate at least once to allow Flickr to know that it can give out your secrets to that application. Most applications could be amended to store the initial authentication token, and then not require authentication every time.

Comment: philosophically, I would agree. This seems intrinsic. I solved this problem by not authenticating and only dealing with public data.

Comment: @user420095: How did you get access to public data without authenticating? My understanding from API is we always need at least the Api Key.